# Framed minipage and `comments` package

Tags: minipage, framed, comments

I am preparing a classroom workbook with two versions: one with answers and one without.
The student version has big, empty, framed boxes to handwrite their answers.  The teacher version has suggested answers written inside this frame.  I have to manually guarantee that framed box will be big enough for a student to write in.

The pagination of the two versions must match so I use a framed minipage of fixed height.  The minipage should not cross a page-break.

Using the MWE below, there seems to be a conflict between the `framebox` command and the `comments` package:
If I delete the lines of the `comments` environment

```
\begin{teacher}
\end{teacher}
```

the frame works fine.

Alternatively, if I delete the `framebox` command, the `comments` package works perfectly.

But if I retain both the frame and the comment environment, it fails, reporting that
`Paragraph ended before \xComment was complete`

How can I get both?  Eventually I want the teacher version to include more complicated things like polyglossia-based languages and images.
Is there a cleaner way to do what I want?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{teacher}
\begin{document}
Please answer this question in the box below:
\bigskip
\framebox{%
\begin{minipage}[0in][5in][t]{\textwidth}
\begin{teacher}
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
\end{teacher}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for your need?  Below I show it with two cases: included and excluded comment.  I also added the `\mbox{}` so that the `minipage` shows as full-width when otherwise empty.

EDITED to get indentations right.  However, I still have not managed to condense the approach into its own environment, as it seems the `teacher` environment is very finicky in how it is packaged.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\fboxsep=10pt\fboxrule=1pt
\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{teacher}
\begin{document}
Please answer this question in the box below:
Please answer this question in the box below:
Please answer this question in the box below:
Please answer this question in the box below:
Please answer this question in the box below:
\bigskip\par
\noindent\setbox0=\hbox{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[0in][5in][t]{\textwidth}%
\begin{teacher}
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
\end{teacher}
\mbox{}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}\framebox{\box0}
\clearpage
\excludecomment{teacher}
Please answer this question in the box below:
\bigskip\par
\noindent\setbox0=\hbox{%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[0in][5in][t]{\textwidth}%
\begin{teacher}
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
\end{teacher}
\mbox{}%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule\relax}\framebox{\box0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it works.  I still don't understand two things.

Comment: @Tim Not sure if I "understand" in the LaTeX sense, but if you elaborate a question, I can share what I know.

Comment: Sorry, caught by edit restrictions.

Comment: Firstly, where is documentation for `hbox`

Comment: secondly, i notice that you firstly define a box and then you frame it.  I tried collapsing this into one big line: \framebox\hbox\minipage etc and it didn't work.

Comment: thirdly, can I easily make your solution into a custom environment with box-height as a parameter, for example: `begin{answer_box}{5in}\\This is the answer}\\end{answer_box}

Comment: fourthly, why doesn't my solution work?????

Comment: that is two things I don't understand, multiplied by two :)

Comment: @Tim `\hbox` is a TeX primitive (see Knuth's "The TeXbook").  I am looking to see if I can collapse the answer into a custom environment, but so far I have not succeeded.  If I do, I will post and alert you.

Comment: @Tim The difficulty seems to be that the `teacher` environment does not "like" being placed inside another (non-`minipage`)environment.  Still thinking...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, look at the `tcolorbox` package or other similar packages which you can completely adjust to your needs. It works completely fine with your comment package.

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{minipage}[0in][5in][t]{\textwidth}
\begin{teacher}
This is a a sample answer from the teacher
\end{teacher}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well.  I preferred the other solution because it didn't involve another package, which reduces the problems of conflicts.